# Awkward dialog box: MZFinance.InAppBuyLoginRequired_message

Tags: macos, mac-appstore

I am getting the following dialog box for a few days:

[image: dialog box]

How can I find out which application is showing it and how can I solve the issue?
I am on Mac OS 10.7.5.

**Edit:**

1. I followed the bassplayer7's answer (moving `/Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration
   /NetworkInterfaces.plist` to trash and restarting) but it didn't solve the problem.
2. I moved the hard drive of one my macbooks to another one. So, this might be the cause of the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Very similar error messages have been noticed by developers and users alike.

Check out [this blog post](http://brooksreview.net/2011/01/mac-app-error/). It's not an identical error message but perhaps this will fix it for you as well:

> AppleCare found the solution and it is rather simple. Now this solution has worked for me, but there is no guaranty that it will work for you.
>
> Solution: Go to Macintosh HD (or whatever you call your HD in Finder) > Library > Preferences > SystemConfiguration
>
> For there look for the file labeled: “NetworkInterfaces.plist”

So, you might test this remedy by making a good backup of your Mac and ensure you either have the network passwords and VPN setup files you need (or can regenerate them / reset your WiFi routers to passwords you know) and delete the NetworkInterfaces.plist file.

If that fails to work, you may need to open a Mac App store support ticket and involve Apple in troubleshooting this further. If you can document the steps needed to reproduce this error, please post a follow up question.

Chances are [there is a bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10828983/in-app-purchase-testing-mzfinance-inappbuyloginrequired-message-sandbox) in some Mac App Store software that was downloaded onto your computer and getting Apple support involved mit fix it for you and others at the same time.

Comment: Thanks bassplayer7 for the answer. It didn't solve the issue. See my edit please.

Comment: @moshen. I've edited the answer to provide two more avenues for help - App Store support and trying to reproduce the issue on a cleanly installed account / Mac. You might live with the error since either would take about 30 minutes to try.